# Object_Detection_Demo: Google protobuf text_format.Merge: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

Reference: [object_detection_tutorial.ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)

NOTE : I have successfully installed everything according to installation instructions [Installation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) and researched regarding this on github but had no luck.

Label maps map indices to category names, so that when our convolution network predicts 5, we know that this corresponds to airplane.

```
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
```

This raises a error as

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

After drilling down in this function **label_map_util.load_labelmap**, below is the used function (load_labelmap)

```
from google.protobuf import text_format
from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2

with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'rb') as fid:
    label_map_string = fid.read()
    label_map = string_int_label_map_pb2.StringIntLabelMap()
    print(type(label_map_string))
    print(type(label_map))
    try:
      text_format.Merge(label_map_string, label_map)
    except text_format.ParseError:
      label_map.ParseFromString(label_map_string)
```

I tried to see the error which is same. But label_map_string is already a Bytes object as you can see in the output. Tried 'r' mode also while reading.

## OUTPUT

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'object_detection.protos.string_int_label_map_pb2.StringIntLabelMap'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-3fce64fd5c00> in <module>()
      5     print(type(label_map))
      6     try:
----> 7       text_format.Merge(label_map_string, label_map)
      8     except text_format.ParseError:
      9       label_map.ParseFromString(label_map_string)

C:\Users\GUS9KOR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\dlnd\lib\site-packages\protobuf-3.3.0-py3.5.egg\google\protobuf\text_format.py in Merge(text, message, allow_unknown_extension, allow_field_number, descriptor_pool)
    475   """
    476   return MergeLines(
--> 477       text.split('\n'),
    478       message,
    479       allow_unknown_extension,

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If found that upgrading from TensorFlow 1.0.0 to TensorFlow 1.2.0 resolved this error. I am using protobuf==3.3.0 on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information about your environment? I've gotten this work on my Windows 10 machine using Anaconda 3. Specifically, whta version of tensorflow are you using, and which version of protoc did you compile the protos with?

Comment: Windows 7, Conda 4.3.22, tensorflow 1.0.0 
protobuf 3.3.0 is installed.

But for compiling protos directory files, I had to use Protobuf binary exe file as mentioned here [https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1591] by  astrung

**For window users : Use protobuf binary : protoc-3.3.0-win32.zip then : \link\to\protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. > then you can import string_int_label_map_pb2**

Comment: Could you try running "print google.protobuf.__version__"? I've seen other users run into similar issues with the protobuf runtime library (not the compiler).

Additionally, could you consider upgrading your tensorflow installation to 1.2? The change is required to run our SSD Model anyways as we use newer TF ops.